# 2SXC: Status: 400 Bad Request - When upadating an existing recordset or adding new recordset to existing list group

Tags: 2sxc

When attempting to make an addition to a 2sxc recordset, or add an item to an existing list group I receive a status 400 bad request alert.

When I try to setup new 2sxc nodes I don't receive the problem, but on existing ones I do. I'm not entirely sure what is causing this, and at an early stage in a sites life it's not terrible to have to replicate the nodes, but on older and larger sites it can become a huge problem. Here is a link to a video example of me running through showing the error on existing nodes, and then creating a new node and being able to add and update records.

I was curious if anyone is familiar with what we might be doing that is causing this. I know we have had this happen on multiple sites and from my experience I believe it happens after we make an additional to the fields for a content type.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/25cy5wblywsw1ld/2sxc-Create-Element-Error.mov?dl=0

Comment: thanks for the movie - this always helps. ATM I can't say we have this behavior anywhere else, but something must be off with the list. My guess is that the page HTML is faulty (tags open/close) and so a wrong parameter is used. Could you shift+click the add-button and review the url to see if it matches what you should expect? Basically you should see the list-id in the items-parameter matching the list-guid in the json of the page (the data-attributes around the template).

Comment: Thanks for the response @iJungleBoy. We scanned through our html and didn't see any errors with open or closed html elements. I also tried utilizing the module on the default theme to see if I could replicate the error, and it persists on the default skin as well using (?SkinSrc=Portals/_default/Skins/Cavalier/main). It is important to note that this error occurs on different pages with different 2sxc data types. Here is a screenshot of one of the template files we are utilizing where we encounter the problem. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8d7iiw6e4x34nx6/2sxc-template.png?dl=0

Comment: What would help me to corner this is if you could publish a detailed insights log of the request which throws the error. Here's how to get this: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/using-2sxc-insights